# Is there a way to show a line above each bar in a bar chart?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a bar Chart, and I want to show a horizontal line above the bar to indicate the peak. Is there a way to achieve this with `echarts` without using a custom renderer?

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
"series": [
    {
        "type": "bar",
        "dimensions": [
            "date",
            "percent",
            "tooltip"
        ],
        "color": "#1976d2",
        "data": [
            [
                "2023-01-11",
                3.230555555555555,
                "3.2"
            ],
            [
                "2023-01-12",
                5.436111111111111,
                "5.4"
            ],
            [
                "2023-01-13",
                7.306481481481481,
                "7.3"
            ],
        ],
        "name": "Mean",
    },
    {
        "type": "custom",
        "dimensions": [
            "date",
            "peak",
            "tooltip"
        ],
        "color": "#d32f2f",
        "renderItem": renderPeakLine,
        "data": [
            [
                "2023-01-11",
                25,
                25
            ],
            [
                "2023-01-12",
                50,
                50
            ],
            [
                "2023-01-13",
                50,
                50
            ],
        ],
        "yAxisIndex": 0,
        "name": "Peak",
    }
],
"xAxis": {
    "show": true,
    "type": "time",
    "axisLabel": {}
},
"yAxis": {
    "show": true,
    "type": "value",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 100,
    "scale": false,
},
"tooltip": {
    "show": true,
    "trigger": "axis",
    "axisPointer": {
        "label": {}
    }
},
"legend": {
    "show": true
}
}

const peakColor = '#d32f2f'

function renderPeakLine(param, api) {
const bandWidth = (param.coordSys.width / param.dataInsideLength) * 0.6
const point = api.coord([api.value(0), api.value(1)])

const value = api.value(2)

// This skips drawing the red line for 0
if (value === 0) return

return {
    type: 'line',
    transition: 'shape',
    z2: 10,
    shape: {
        x1: point[0] - bandWidth / 2,
        x2: point[0] + bandWidth / 2,
        y1: point[1],
        y2: point[1],
    },
    style: api.style({
        fill: null,
        stroke: api.visual('color'),
        lineWidth: 2,
    }),
}
}


myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.0.4/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" style="width: 500px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Comment: I want to achieve the same result as the code does but without using a custom renderer function.

Answer (score 0):

What you described sounds like [candlestick](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-candlestick) chart type.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
  xAxis: {
    data: ["2023-01-11", "2023-01-12", "2023-01-13"]
  },
  yAxis: {
    show: true,
    type: "value",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    scale: false,
},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'candlestick',
      data: [
        [
          0,
          3.230555555555555,
          0,
          25
        ],
        [
          0,
          5.436111111111111,
          0,
          50
        ],
        [
          0,
          7.306481481481481,
          0,
          50
        ],
      ],
    }
  ]
};


myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.0.4/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" style="width: 500px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Comment: It is very similar, but I would like the lines to be horizontal and not vertical.

Comment: Oh I see. It changes everything. It's said "vertical line" in your post, please change it to not confuse futur readers ;)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I updated the post.